# How to write a table driven test for a generic method?

Tags: go, generics

I have a simple generic method that looks like this:

```
func L[T ~string](s T) string {
   return string(s)
}
```

I can easily exercise this in code like so:

```
type T string


L(T("foo"))
L("foo")
```

I'm trying to figure out how to design a table driven test to also exercise the method. Where I'm getting caught up is in the generic field needed in the struct. So I have a test that looks something like:

```
TestL(t *testing.T) {
  tests := []struct{
     in ??? // This is where I'm stuck
     want string
  }{
     { in: T("foo"), want: "foo" },
     { in: "foo", want: "foo" },
  }
  for _, tc := range tests {
    t.Run("", func(t *testing.T) {
      if got := L(tc.in); got != tc.want {
         t.Errorf("got %s, want %s", got, tc.want)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

I tried doing something like `[][T ~string]struct{ in T }` but that apparently can't work with the anonymous struct, so then I pulled it into its own type `type test[T ~string] struct`.

This sort of works but requires me to instantiate a specific type: `tests := []test[string]{}` or `tests := []test[T]{}`. I could do multiple testing blocks for each type but -

I'm looking for a way to ideally, declare an anonymous struct `tests := []struct{}{}`, and allow that struct to take the generic values that satisfy the `~string` constraint without needing multiple calls.